# How to use strtok_r() to pass in value to an array

Tags: c

I am writing a simple shell. I need to add a history feature on this shell, which will allow me to check the prior commands received by my shell.
I have been trying for so long, I can not figure out why my command [] array is NULL here

```
for (command[numargs] = strtok_r(buf," ",&inner_ptr);
                         command[numargs];
                         command[numargs] = strtok_r(NULL," ",&inner_ptr))
                        ++numargs;

                        printf("%s \n",command[numargs]);
```

printf("%d \n",numargs);
                if (numargs)
                    execute(&command[numargs]);

so which means my shell is always executing a NULL

//shell code. Boojum, Thank you for fixing the code with the error of printing two "?->"

//Shell

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
#define ARGLENGTH  100
int execute(char *command[]);

int main()
{
int option;
int his_size=0;
char buffer[ARGLENGTH];
char *history[his_size];
int numargs = 0;
printf("Press 1 to input from keyboard, 2 to input from file .mshrc\n");
    scanf("%d",&option);
switch (option){
    case 1: 
        while(1)
        {
            printf("?-> ");
            if (fgets(buffer, ARGLENGTH, stdin))
            {
                char *outer_ptr=NULL;
                for (char *buf=strtok_r(buffer, ";\n\r", &outer_ptr);
                     buf;
                     buf=strtok_r(NULL, ";\n\r", &outer_ptr) )
                {
                    if (strcmp(buf, "exit") == 0){
                        return 0;
                    }
                    if (strcmp(buf, "history") == 0){
                        for(int a=0;a<=numargs;a++){
                            printf("command history: %s \n", history[a]);
                        }
                    }

                    char *command[1000000];
                    char *inner_ptr=NULL;
                    //int numargs = 0;

                    for (command[numargs] = strtok_r(buf," ",&inner_ptr);
                         command[numargs];
                         command[numargs] = strtok_r(NULL," ",&inner_ptr))
                        ++numargs;

                        printf("%s \n",command[numargs]);
                        printf("%d \n",numargs);
                    if (numargs)
                        execute(&command[numargs]);
                }
            }
        }

    case 2:
        FILE *fr;

        fr=fopen("example.txt","rt");
           if( fr == NULL )
               {
                  perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
                  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
               }

            while(fgets(buffer, ARGLENGTH, fr) != NULL ){
                char *outer_ptr=NULL;
                for (char *buf=strtok_r(buffer, ";\n\r", &outer_ptr);
                     buf;
                     buf=strtok_r(NULL, ";\n\r", &outer_ptr) )
                {
                    if (strcmp(buf, "exit") == 0)
                        return 0;
                    int numargs = 0;
                    char *command[1000000];
                    char *inner_ptr=NULL;
                    for (command[numargs] = strtok_r(buf," ",&inner_ptr);
                         command[numargs];
                         command[numargs] = strtok_r(NULL," ",&inner_ptr))
                        ++numargs;
                    if (numargs)
                        execute(command);

                }
            }
            fclose(fr);
            return main();

    }
        return 0;
}   

int execute(char *command[])
{
    int pid,exitstatus;
    pid = fork();
    if( pid==-1 ){
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    else if( pid==0 ){
           execvp(command[0], command);
            perror("execution failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
                while (wait(&exitstatus) != pid);
        }
 }
```

Comment: This won't compile in C. It is C++

Comment: Why did you include `iostream` if you're using `printf` anyways? Why are you compiling your code as C++ even though it's clearly C?

Comment: Why `numargs` in `printf("?-> ", numargs);`?

Comment: `fgets` might not "return" a `'\n'` into the array. I recommend refactoring out several functions so that each does only one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're reading each line in as an argument for a single command and then executing it when given a blank line.  e.g.,

```
?-> ls
?-> -al
?->
```

will give an extended directory listing.

If you want to just want to use space to separate the parameters, this is probably a good use for `strtok()`.  I suspect that something like this is more what you want:

```
int main()
{
    char *command[1000000];
    int numargs = 0;
    char buffer[ARGLENGTH];

    while(1) {
        printf("?-> ", numargs);
        if( fgets(buffer, ARGLENGTH, stdin) && *buffer != '\n' ) {
            command[numargs++] = strtok(buffer, " \n\r");
            while (command[numargs++] = strtok(NULL, " \n\r"))
                ;
            if( numargs > 0 ){
                /* command[numargs] = NULL; -- No longer needed, strtok() does this */
                execute(command);
                numargs = 0;
            }
        }
        if (command[0][0] == 'e'){
            break;}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are other edge-case issues that you'll want to take a look at: blank lines, for example, or lines that begin with "e".  But that should help get you started.

EDIT:  Here's something a little closer to how I would write this to include splitting commands on semicolons.  I made a couple of stylistic changes this time as well, namely moving variable declarations closer to where they are first used.

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("?-> ");
        char buffer[ARGLENGTH];
        if (fgets(buffer, ARGLENGTH, stdin))
        {
            char *outer_ptr=NULL;
            for (char *buf=strtok_r(buffer, ";\n\r", &outer_ptr);
                 buf;
                 buf=strtok_r(NULL, ";\n\r", &outer_ptr) )
            {
                if (strcmp(buf, "e") == 0)
                    return 0;
                int numargs = 0;
                char *command[1000000];
                char *inner_ptr=NULL;
                for (command[numargs] = strtok_r(buf," ",&inner_ptr);
                     command[numargs];
                     command[numargs] = strtok_r(NULL," ",&inner_ptr))
                    ++numargs;
                if (numargs)
                    execute(command);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Boojum. I understand strtok is for spliting the string. But can you explain why is your condition  " \n\r"?

Comment: I think what your strtok(buffer, " \n\r"); means you only take the buffer and then ignore the " \n\r"?

Comment: @perryfanfan - The " \n\r" means that it will split the string at any one of ' ', '\n', or '\r'.  So "   my \r\r\r\n\r     string \n" will be split into just "my" and "string".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have one more question relates to strtok(). I have been trying to write the semicolon feature to my shell. So if I type "ls;top" Then my shell will execute "ls" first then execute "top". And I looked up a lot of sample codes about strtok(). I think the string been chopped should be all stored in command in my case, right? So I tried to use a loop to implement the semicolon feature. Everytime I chop the string when I see a ";", I execute it, then I keep going. This is my plan. But I tried so many times and it won't work. I will post my code in my next comments.

Comment: Please give me some help, I have been trying for so long, and could not get it work.

Comment: @perryfanfan - So what you need is to first split on either ';', '\n', or '\r' to get each command, then split those on ' ' to get the arguments.  The `strtok_r()` variant will let you do that.  In fact, there's a example of a two-level split like that on the Linux man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r

And yes, all of the parts of the string remain in the command array.  The `strtok()` commands just replace the delimiters with '\0' to terminate the strings and return a pointer to a character inside the array where the piece begins.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help again, I have edited my code using strtok_r(). And I think I the buffer string in my code now is splitted and stored in my command[] array. But when I input ls;ls, my code will only execute the second ls, and it won't recognize the first ls. I will post my edited code on top, please advise!

Comment: My guess was, after I stored all pieces of buffer into my command[] array. Every piece before the last piece does not have the '\0', only the last piece has it. So it only execute the last piece. If I am right, how should I add a '\0' for all the pieces before last one?

Comment: @perryfanfan - `strtok_r()` takes care of inserting the '\0' for you.  The two things I'd try in the newly posted code are, (1) don't look for ' ' in the outer strtok_r, and (2) move the if that immediately follows the outer loop inside to the end of the outer loop.  Otherwise, you only actually execute the last command.  Any previous ones get replaced.

Comment: I edited the way to taught me, I think I am getting closer. Now, if I input ls;ls . The code will execute ls twice, but then give me a segment fault.

Comment: @perryfanfan - Try changing the loop around execute back to just execute(command).  Right now, it's trying to execute each argument as its own command, plus the garbage after the last argument.

Comment: I think the reason that is causing this segment fault is numarg=0. But I do not know how to solve the problem.  Can you make some changes on my code, please?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. I will study your code until I understand it completely

Comment: My pleasure.  If you're satisfied, feel free to accept my answer. :-)

Comment: Hi, Boojum. Sorry about bother you again, now I need to add a history feature on my shell. So I can see the user command input history. So I think on your edited code, you have split buffer then store to buf, and then split buf and store to command[] array, right? Thus I think if I need to add the history feature, I only need to access what is stored in comments. But what I found out was that command[numargs] is always null. Why is that? please advise. Thank you so much for you help